# Opposite of "isAssignableFrom" for a Class object?

Tags: java, class

Given a Class object, how do I check if one of its "ancestors" is a certain class?
Is there an alternative to call getSuperClass several times?

Comment: What is confusing? I'd like to clarify.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Given a class `c1`, you want to know if one of its ancestors is `c2`?

Won't

```
c2.isAssignableFrom(c1)
```

do the trick?

Comment: Wow, so simple, so true. Thank you!

Comment: It would be nice, if there was a method named `isAssignableTo()` in order to make thinking easier. `c2.isAssignableFrom(c1)` is similar to `c1.newInstance() instanceof c2`. So calling it the other way round would be more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just flip the isAssignableFrom(...) logic, as follows?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Cat cat = new Cat();
    final Siamese siamese = new Siamese();

    // All print true
    System.out.println(cat.isSuperclass(Animal.class));
    System.out.println(siamese.isSuperclass(Animal.class));
    System.out.println(siamese.isSuperclass(Cat.class));

    // All print false
    System.out.println(cat.isSuperclass(Siamese.class));
    System.out.println(siamese.isSuperclass(Integer.class));
}

public static class Animal {

}

public static class Cat extends Animal {

    public boolean isSuperclass(final Class<?> cls) {
        return cls.isAssignableFrom(getClass());
    }
}

public static class Siamese extends Cat {

}
```